How do I add EXIF GPS Data to an Image JPEG on IOS
I have a solution which works on Android using EXIFInterface.
However I struggle to get it working on IOS as there seems to be no interface in oder to do that.
What I found so far:
I am sure something is missing. Unfortunately neither ChatGPT could hint me in the right direction. Google Search also yielded no results.
In the end I need to add GPS information to an existing Image.
Any advice?
Plattform C#, .NET MAUI
Tried many thing, nothing seems to work.

there are many .NET EXIF libraries.  What have you tried and what specific problem are you having?

Have solved it.
Here is how to get EXIF working on MAUI:
Get this NUGET Package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExifLibNet
Works on Android and IOS.
Now if you use MediaPicker, the problem on IOS is that it creates an .PNG file even though it has the JPEG as file ending. In order to solve this, use the solution provided here:
MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync() Image rotated 90 degree
Only the IOS platform specific implementation is required. Android is sufficient to use the media picker.
Now it works and I can write the GPS information.

I have used ImageSharp which proved to be the best bet for iOS and all other platforms.
Reason for not choosing ExifLibNet is because it is not supported/worked on actively anymore and more importantly it doesn't support HEIC/HEIF images. These are default image types for iOS.
ImageSharp provides support for many image types with both read and write along with support for all gps tag.
https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.html
Although it doesn't support HEIC/HEIF officially but it provides custom decoders and encoders to be built on top of their apis to support that. This is the one I used https://github.com/hey-red/ImageSharp.Heif which allows to add support for these image types with the following code
var decoderOptions = new DecoderOptions()
{
    Configuration = new Configuration(
        new AvifConfigurationModule(), 
        new HeifConfigurationModule())
};



Thanks for the information. Yes we found out that it is not actively developed anymore but for our use case, it is sufficient for now. Later we may investigate ImageSharp.
